# Как убрать маркеры компаний на подложке карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как убрать описание компаний?
Чтобы при случайном нажатии на компанию не появлялся балун с ее описанием.
Либо вообще скрыть их.
В документации прочитал про опцию `options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity` , но она почему то не работает.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>Пример работы с RemoteObjectManager.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="//yandex.st/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="//yandex.st/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&coordorder=latlong&mode=debug"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(function () {
            var myMap = window.map = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
                center: [55.6623162095321, 37.5468326405449],
                zoom: 18,
                yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
            }, {
                // minZoom: 5
            });

            var loadingObjectManager = new ymaps.LoadingObjectManager('/find?bbox=%b', {
                // Шаблон названия callback-функции, в которую сервер должен обернуть ответ.
                paddingTepmlate: "myCallback_%b",
                splitRequests: false,
                clusterize: true
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(loadingObjectManager);
        });

        function makeOffer() {
            alert('offer');
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #YMapsID {
            width: 900px;
            height: 480px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Серверная кластеризация с помощью ymaps.LoadingObjectManager и NodeJS + MongoDB.</p>
            <div id="YMapsID"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался благодаря   https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/otklyuchit-standartnye-baluny

Нужно было перенести `yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity` во вторые ковычки так:

```
  var myMap = window.map = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
            center: [55.6623162095321, 37.5468326405449],
            zoom: 18,
        }, {
            // minZoom: 5
            yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true
        });
```